# how to handle box.net download responce in php

Tags: php, api, curl, download, box-api

i am trying to download a file using box.net using API in php.
As per the documentation i wrote up the code.

but in response i am getting some strange texts.
here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/files/3934139624/content ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: BoxAuth api_key={MyApikey}&auth_token={Mytoken}"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
die('DIE');
```

I am getting response something like this:

> PK!Ðòš-[Content_Types].xml ¢( ´UËNÃ0¼#ñ‘¯¨qË!Ô´G¨Dù×Þ´‰mÙÛ×ß³IšA›ˆ†^"EÑÎÌÎÎnÆÓ]žEðA[“°QH¯~ÉŸb üv8¼ãÒƒ,0ØdüF¼VÍ„ÇW‘ßZ¯xj-‹b‚cÑcUWP'L8—i)„óQ?H6Mµeå:'ª¸€sÞJZË³¸¾) ùdü©Xg=ïH[e‡‡,üõÐfL•¥²°Ò.´0´·uPvÒž¦»v˜3Üis¡M­ÿ¤³ÎàÉ×ÿSÝ)"à>»DP*ÜNz0êBI­‘Û$Ð¼fÞºÀi+zŠ P ´0"f3°£\…È¾TºI  S‘ÌõŒ«º¾ÇôWš™¦ÚY igï@µÇX6_Ö]7~ fïØË‰ÈaoÙ.b*lIÆrj)õ,l0Ï%‘b¬ 6ài¢ÕõDÿ_‹Ž…, ¡  ‰Ïó|uœZ^tÙ¢yÇ¯;!Y,}{ûCƒ³/h>ÿÿPK!¿hJä1>word/*rels/document.xml.rels ¢( ¬”ËNÃ0E÷HüCä=qR q'æ>¾ƒ“‘ˆsµà©WÃ-ŽÌEî›nâ>ðÍqã¨Í§y±3ÆóüükeìE±ty’àÕ³üÍé»¦ÏÖ¤KLÏhóÊŸi¾IàˆpzÒŽ¹ç?}xÛxx;ùgïÐ¥f7Yô KéMèwÄÆÇÐEïúÃF§³ß9ètÏ7ÌKWxÐ/žñ¡“ùéâ;W…—Ô•¯bú%B×óù§ìv îãã¡ˆ“ô£ 8ÜílìÐqq~x|!Ã4Á1Nâ ñaãVš+¾•ËÓr¤ØLe'õc"ójS“Œ(ñR'»>wbriê’6œ,•ôçPøH†.ÔO«<çµ¼G›[¯ ‹`Ÿ~ëÈŒcñ)“ )ò<­4/nÌ—­ôEÛþßpÄÙ÷æ¬Û?xg«\Ã–îÐƒSäÀ•Ç°tÒ(¾‹³ƒwïg˜³ÕKøŒ;ù¾.†ì, l©´ªµÐm¯]‰ŠTíßnÁ¿·ß¤/ë»–ª”ì§“6õ“^Qð-wô—Qð]6bé   à²@ÆûÍ#¡™˜×Fa'™Â†êMî'ÂÛ¿U*XÆÞ/¾\ÁÜl X5HñKÕ˜sØ8EÌ/!Ð²ÃÐeq”µ±dº¨É…â›‚R—7ÐŠU¹iØF:h±FÎç¢àõð¾ôÈ!˜&æ',AD`SÈP¸L‘M.úìäpow*½Ý(¥Ú·R ãpK0è7^;¿Lë4f¤P­3Ì…#M s´ï¡Ü:…(@à(1ß;9|÷S½°T4Ï¹F²ì%“$åÁf“tÖØ©â¼ªR&˜`nn†)@éóÒfŽBC?‰ð€()ÄÝ(%LNËñ)V^«ÞÛ¶[5+Í>jÀ£WlŽ÷¡¿)ÁoôFBû›CÕ©ë­Ü™ÖI¦`æÖQ×Æ¤HX-Ä³ž^ÀDûs“ …Ø}

Can any one tell me how can i handle such kind of response?
thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like compressed content. Try to apply a few uncompress functions like for gzip and bzip2. Actually it looks like pkzip to me.

Comment: Oh, and most likely the content type (including any compression) is also specified inside the response headers. You can get those too with cURL and take a look there.

Answer (score 0):

As per box.net api documentation:

> The response to this request will simply be the complete data of the
>   file itself.

So all you need to save file content locally.

In response header, you need to `check content-type`, right now it is `XML`

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$fp = fopen('test.xml','wb');
fwrite($fp, $result);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

@GBD following comes in response header:

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 09:11:51 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-control: private
>   Location: https://dl.boxcloud.com/bc/1/85f471520cf611a05025a5f/JolueqOGpciD6dgYhecNBoVpYxkvmYe1ZLheZor6BF4DUBIelMQTkFwYIys3nIibNIIEHUp447tBZLaXDzIbNQ,,/a44510a2b21219463fade41d6b36dabf/
>   Content-Length: 0
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: nginx
>   Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 09:11:52 GMT
>   Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
>   Content-Length: 19944
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-control: private
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="cloud computing proposal.docx";filename*=UTF-8''cloud%20computing%20proposal.docx
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes

And saving file in xml also,couldn't b opened.